# ASP.NET MVC – Use Html.BeginForm to pass model data and non-model hidden field value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, html.beginform

I’m using BeginForm to pass model data (i.e. last_coffe_time) which works fine. However I also wanted to pass to controller ClientDateTime value stored in hidden field which is not a part of the model. 
I don’t know how do do it, at best I can pass ClientDateTime as static string but I can't figure out how to dynamically read hidden field for value and pass that value to controller.

Someone please help. Thank you

**View**:

```
@model SleepNotes.Models.Diary

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Diary", new { ClientDateTime = "ClientDateTime" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.Hidden("ClientDateTime", new { id = "ClientDateTime" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_coffe_time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_coffe_time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_coffe_time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
    <!--Set ClientDateTime-->
<script>
    var a = new Date()
    var month = a.getMonth() + 1;
    document.getElementById('ClientDateTime').value = a.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + a.getFullYear() + " " + a.getHours() + ":" + a.getMinutes() + ":" + a.getSeconds();
</script>
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,last_coffe_time")] Diary Diary, string ClientDateTime)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //ClientDateTime from view ...do something here

        db.Entry(Diary).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
    return View(Diary);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? You POST method has a parameter `ClientDateTime` which will contain the value of the hidden input

Comment: Problem I have is that at the controller value I receive is text: ClienntDateTime instead of actual vale (i.e. "06/05/2016 20:36). Thank you

Comment: Remove `new { ClientDateTime = "ClientDateTime" }` from your `BeginForm()` method. And just use `@Html.Hidden("ClientDateTime")` - there is no  point trying to set the `id` attribute to exactly the same value that it already is. And then throw all this away and do it properly by using a view model.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I removed new { ClientDateTime = "ClientDateTime" } from BeginForm() method, and now I’m able to access ClientDateTime in my controller. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You script can just be `document.getElementById('ClientDateTime').value = new Date().toISOString();` and the parameter in your method should be `DateTime ClientDateTime` (not `string`)

Comment: Stephen, can I ask to respond to my question in a form of an answer so that I can mark it as answered. Thank you

Comment: Sure - need a break, but will do so in an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `new { ClientDateTime = "ClientDateTime" }` from the `BeginForm()` method so the vale is not added as a route parameter (and therefore not bound to your `string ClientDateTime` parameter in the `Edit()` method.

Side note: since your wanting to submit a `DateTime` value, your parameter should be `DateTime ClientDateTime` (not `string`) and your script can be simplified to

```
document.getElementById('ClientDateTime').value = new Date().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions,

1. I suggest you to have a ModelView between your Model and View. That
   modalview should have the ClientDateTime.
2. You can use **ajax post** and send 2 parameters (yourmodal, string) to controller or you
   can pass the ClientDateTime as querystring. There are lots of
   examples about it.

Hope helps.

Comment: OP wants to redirect in the POST method so using ajax is hardly a good option